# Problem with using Curve from mesh

Tags: bevel, bezier-curves

I tried to make a tube by using the vertex replicated from object(not add bezier curve),but I add the bevel thickness, it seems flat not like I prefer to. How can I solve this problem?

[image: enter image descr**strong text**iption here]

Comment: Does the object have uniform scale ? Try CTRL + A > Apply scale